# RESTful search centering on specific record within a larger query set

Tags: rest, pagination, paging, wcf-data-services

So I have a query that returns lets say 1000 records.  I'm using paging to grab sections of that, and I know the total number of records due to the $inlinecount=allpages tag.  I'd like to be able to grab a specific record, and know where in the 1000 records it lands.  Let's say the record I'm looking for actually lands on record number 481, is there a way to figure that out?  If I can know that, I can figure out which paging group I need to grab to get to the result.

My goal is to show the user the same list, unfiltered, but focus on the record they are looking for.  They then can scroll backwards or forwards from that record as if they had just jumped to the middle of the total records.

Is there a tricky way to query RESTful data services to do something like what I'm asking?